# ASP.NET Forms Authentication redirects to IP address rather than domain name

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis-7, forms-authentication

We have set up an ASP.NET website for a customer. The site uses Forms authentication via a page called logon.aspx. We are hosting the server on the internet and the customer has created a local DNS passthrough to allow their users (who do not have direct internet access) to use the site.

This works as long as the customers connect directly to the Logon page `http://my.domain.local/logon.aspx`, but if they try to access the root of the site, they get redirected to the IP address`http://1.2.3.4/logon.aspx`  which is inaccessible from within their network.

How can I get this redirect to point to the domain name instead. I have tried adding logon.aspx as the default page of the site in IIS but that does not prevent the redirect. I have also tried setting the host name in IIS but that does not work.

The site is .NET 3.5 on IIS 7 and is the root web site (rather than a web application). Any suggestions of things to try will be gratefully received.

Comment: In your web.config, check that the [loginUrl (and defaultUrl)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) are relative urls to your app root.

Comment: Thank-you for the suggestion. Yes, the loginUrl and defaultUrl both just contain the file names. As far as I can tell, the IP address is not stored anywhere in the web site because installed the website before the IT guys knew where they were going to host it.

Comment: Sounds like there may be a HttpModule or HttpHandler intercepting calls somewhere. Have you tried a network analyzer like Fiddler, Wireshark to see where the redirect is coming from?